# Proving a function is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: [1,∞)→ \mathbb{R}$ be a uniformly continuous function. Prove that $\frac{f(x)}{x}: [1,∞)→ \mathbb{R}$  is bounded from above and below.

I've tried bounding it from above, by splitting it into two intervals; $[1, M]$ and $[M,∞)$. I know that in the $[1, M]$, the new function is uniformly continuous, and therefore bounded (since it's a closed interval); however, I'm not sure how to handle $[M,∞)$.
Any clues or directions, as well as the solution, would be great.

Comment: That's weird, I've searched for a similar one and didn't find it. My bad, I apologize. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Uniform continuity of $f$ is actually stronger than the continuity of $\frac{f(x)}{x}$.

Bigger hint:

> it's a general fact that if $f$ is uniformly continuous, then there exist positive constants $M, C_1, C_2$ such that $|f(x)|<C_1x+C_2$ whenever $|x|>M$. Try to prove this (directly from the definition of uniform continuity). Do you see that it immediately implies the desired conclusion?

Comment: Huh, I didn't know this fact. I'll look  onto that. Yes, then that question is solved. Thank you!